# insert data from textbox to database

Tags: plugins

Please help me in finding error

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: User Information Form
Description: Just another user information form plugin. Simple but flexible!!!
Author: Hafizur Rahman
Author URI: https://babkingcircular.com.bd/
Version:1.0.0
*/
/*
Some Texts
*/
$path = preg_replace ('/wp-content.*$/','',_DIR_);
require_once ($path.'/wp-load.php');
function userinf(){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        global $wpdb;
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $wpdb->insert('wp_userinfor',array('fname'=>$fname,'lname'=>$lname));
    }
}   
    ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>First Name:</label><input type="text" name="lname" />
    <br />
    <label>First Name:</label><input type="text" name="lname" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value]="Submit" />
</form>
<?php

add_shortcode ('userinfor', 'userinf');
?>
```

Comment: Explain please, what this code is used for

Comment: And what you're trying to do that isn't working, and what specifically you see - a PHP error or warning, or something else? Why are you loading wp-load? Is this a separate page you post to not loaded through WordPress?